# Using a column in interval subtraction

Tags: mysql

I am using MySQL 5.5 and have the following query

```
SELECT a.id, a.created
FROM apps AS a
    INNER JOIN bats AS b ON a.bat_id = b.id
WHERE a.created > NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY
```

The above query works fine. No issues. However, I would like to modify the query to be like below

```
SELECT a.id, a.created
FROM apps AS a
    INNER JOIN bats AS b ON a.bat_id = b.id
WHERE a.created > NOW() - INTERVAL b.unit_duration DAY
```

Any suggestions / tips on how I may achieve the same? Thanks in advance...

Comment: **how I may achieve the same** what did you mean by this?

Comment: When I try to execute the second query - I get an error. Apparently column names are not allowed in INTERVAL subtraction - but I would like to know if there is a workaround or an alternative way to get the same result

Comment: Could you please post the exact error message?

Comment: henry's answer is the solution - my 'unit_duration' column was defined as VARCHAR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to modify your second query, I just tested it on MySQL 5.5 and it runs, albeit slow using a column name. The column I used was an integer, so if you're not using an integer column you might need to use the Convert Function on it.